# How to safely shut down Sidekiq on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sidekiq

I guess I need a sanity check here because if I want to prevent any sidekiq jobs from ending prematurely, Heroku Redis should handle this for me?

When I want to push new changes to a production site, I put the application in maintenance mode: `heroku maintenance:on`. Now when I do this and run `heroku ps` I can see both my `web` process and my `worker` (i.e. sidekiq) are up still (makes sense because its just to prevent users having access to the site).

If I shut down the `worker` dyno with a command like this: `heroku ps:stop worker` after the site is in maintenance mode, will this safely stop sidekiq workers before it does down? Also, from Sidekiq's documentation:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment#heroku

It mentions a `-t N` switch where N is a number in seconds but that Heroku has a hard limit of allowing a process 30 seconds to shut down on its own. Am I correct that if I stop the `worker` process with the heroku command, it will give any currently running jobs `N` seconds to finish before giving it a `SIGTERM` signal?

If not, what additional steps do I need to take to make sure Sidekiq has safely shut down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are fine. Heroku sends SIGTERM when you call `ps:stop`. Sending SIGTERM tells Sidekiq to shut down within N seconds. Your worker dyno should be safely down within 30 seconds.